# Does LiveUSB work on computer with different processor?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 64-bit, architecture

I want to create liveUSB on part of my flash stick. I made a partition with GParted and downloaded `.iso` file of Ubuntu 19 from the official website to mount with `gnome-disk-utility`.

I noticed that the iso file has "amd64" in the name. But I intend to use this USB not only on amd computers!

Is that important? Will the live USB work on PC with Intel/other processor?

Comment: AMD64 is the official name of x86_64 because it was created by the company AMD.  Intel tried to get the marketplace to move to an incompatible IA64 and failed; the marketplace wanted to run 32bit software on their 64bit processors and went with AMD64.  AMD64 works with Intel or AMD cpus (if you bought intel - a tiny fraction went to licensing fees to AMD is all it means)

Comment: If your cpu is ARM architecture, the NO the amd64 won't boot, likewise if your box is s390, ppc, ppc64el it likewise won't boot (applies to any other architecture too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, there are two versions of `.iso` available for any Linux distro: `amd64` and `i386`(`i386` ISO files for Ubuntu are discontinued). For simplicity, you can assume that `i386` is for `32-bit` system and `amd64` is for a 64-bit system. It does not matter if your processor is AMD or Intel.

Suppose you have one computer with an AMD processor and another computer having an Intel processor, you can use the same live USB for both systems provided both are having same Instruction set either `32-bit` or `64-bit`

Comment: There is no longer a 32bit version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu will only work on 64bit capable computers, For 32bit computers, Lubuntu is available.

Answer (score 4):

AMD64 is the official name of x86_64 because it was created by the company AMD. Intel tried to get the marketplace to move to an incompatible IA64 and failed; the marketplace wanted to run 32bit software on their 64bit processors and went with AMD64.

AMD64 works with *Intel* or *AMD* brand cpus (if you bought intel - a tiny fraction went in licensing fees to AMD).

If your cpu is **ARM** architecture, the NO the ***AMD64*** ISO won't boot, likewise if your box is **s390**, **ppc**, **ppc64el**, **IA64** or any other architecture it likewise won't boot.

AMD64 won't boot on i686 cpus, you'll get a message like "*This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU*".

The linux kernel treats *i386*, *i486*, *i586* & *i686* as upgrades of the same architecture; but Debian (*and thus Ubuntu*) call all of these architectures just i386, thus any x86 (32-bit) ISO will have i386 in it's name.